# Differences between RHV and KVM

Tags: rhel, virtual-machine, kvm, rhev

What is/are the difference(s) between RedHat-Virtualization/(RHV) and Kernel-based Virtual Machine/(KVM)?

I got the gist that they both are type-1 hypervisor. But I couldn't find definitive architectural differences anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Red Hat Virtualization](https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-virtualization/) product page.

> Red Hat® Virtualization® is a complete open-source virtualization solution, derived from the Red Hat Enterprise Linux® kernel, Kernel-based Virtual Machine (KVM) technology, and oVirt virtualization management projects.

Red Hat Virtualization is their paid support offering of the upstream [oVirt](https://www.ovirt.org/) enterprise virtualization solution. Red Hat Virtualization is not a singular hypervisor of any sort. It is the orchestration and management engine and tools to run one or more KVM/QEMU hypervisors.

So to cut through the extraneous verbiage... RHEV is KVM. But on a Red Hat system with their licensing for their added tools, content, packaging, and support.